# Reading large XML file and inserting data into database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

I have large XML files, up to 4 to 5 GB.

I manage to read it with the `XmlReader` but now want to add the values into a database

I have used simple insert queries to add the values to database and got stuck, it takes more than 2 hours to insert values into database for 2 GB file. Is there other approach that will be more efficient adding the values from the XML file into the database?

The XML files have attributes and their values also new to be added to the database.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and .NET.

Thanks..

Comment: Do you create one connection for all inserts or connection per insert?

Comment: one conncetion for all insert..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a "batch" style operation.  Consider taking a different approach:

1. Create an xsl transform that converts your xml into a BULK INSERT statement
2. Save the resulting sql script to a file or build a command string
3. Execute the sql script

See [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

This approach will almost certainly be higher performing than iterating over the XML and inserting a row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

bcp is usually the quickest way...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can interop XmlBulkLoad. May be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806.aspx) can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get faster response if you read the XML file directly from SQL Server.

Its a 3 step process, simplified looks like:

1) declare @doc xml = 'your xml here'
   declare @handler int

2) EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handler OUTPUT, @doc

3) select * from OPENXML(@handler, '/ROOT/Path/To/Data')

Comment: are you suggesting he pastes 2GB of xml into line 1?